# Can I use Google Play Developer API on Android device?

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I want to get expiration date of an subscription (in-app billing) but it seems to be that Google Play Developer API is designed just for server (backend) use. Am I right?

There is another way to get full subscription details?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. According to google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/), "you can access the REST APIs directly via HTTP." Here is the [reference](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/) of what URLs you would need to use.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke it requires authentication with google DEVELOPER's account via Oauth2 (or service account). I can't use service account on user's device